ROS 2 Humble RQT image view doesnt appear
I recently installed ROS 2 Humble again and i used to open RQT to view an image topic from a camera used in a gazebo simulation, but after this installation the view option doesnt appear in RQT Pluguins > Visualization anymore. Any thoughts?

Have you verified image_view is installed? Have you tried to start rqt with the flag --force-discover?
